# I can't find any primary key in some of my relations

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, relation

Alright so I read from somewhere

> Every table should have a primary key

But some of my tables don't seem to behave!
I'd also like to know whether the relations as I'm using are fine or I need to dissolve them further, I'm open to suggestions.

The relations are

> Dealers(DealerId(PK),DealerName)
>
> Order(DealerId(FK),OrderDate,TotalBill)
>
> Sales(DealerId(FK),ItemType,OrderDate,Quantity,Price)

P.S. I can't make a table named Items(ItemCode,Type,Price) Because the price is variable for different dealers. And all the constraints i.e not null + check that I needed are dealt with already just didn't mention.

**1. Are the relations dissolved well?**

**2. Should I care about setting primary keys in the tables that don't have it already?**

Helpful responses appreciated.

Comment: 2. Yes you should. You will have an `orderID` as a PK and `dealerID` as a FK for example

Comment: In the Order relation?

Comment: Both Order and Sales. You should always have a Primary key. And I'm guessing an order has a couple of items from sales. So your FK in Sales should probably be `orderID` then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you should add an auto increment integer field to Order and Sales and set that to be the primary key.

In Relational Database Theory, you can sometimes identify a sub-set of the fields to use as a primary key, as long as those columns are non-null and unique.  However, (1) the order table cannot have a primary key from DealerID and OrderDate because a dealer could make two orders on the same date.  Maybe even for the same amount, which would mean that no sub-set of fields is unique, and (2) even when familiar data can uniquely identify the data, an auto-increment integer can be a good key.

I also think that you want a foreign key from Sales to Order.  You are probably using DealerId and OrderDate for joins, but this will not work correctly if a dealer makes two orders on the same date.

Finally, take advice like

> Every table should have a primary key

with a grain of salt.  Linking tables used for many-to-many relationships can work perfectly fine without a primary key, although a primary key can be an improvement, since it will make deleting records easier, and if you don't have a primary key on a linking table, I would still recommend a unique index on all the fields, in which case *that* can be the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need separate **Sales** Table ?

```
Dealers(DealerId(PK),DealerName)
Order(OrderId(PK), DealerId(FK),OrderDate, ItemType, Quantity,Price)
```

Also,

```
TotalBill (can be calculated) = Quantity * Price
```

Answer (score 0):

**About the question 1** you should answer this question:

```
A sale can be made without an order?
```

If yes, your DealerId(FK) in Sales is alright, assuming that a sale will only exist if a dealer made it.

If no, you should put an OrderId(FK) in Sales, instead of DealerId(FK). If a sale belongs to an order, this order belongs do a dealer, so you already have the relation from dealers to sales.

**About the question 2**, you should have primary keys on your tables, because this is the way you have to select, update and delete some specific item on your database. Remembering that a primary key is not always an auto increment column.

And **about the Items table**, if the price is variable to different dealers, so you have an M to N relationship between Dealers and Items, which means you could have an intermediate table like this example:

```
DealerItemPrices(DealerId(FK), ItemId(FK), Price)
```

And these two Foreign Keys should be Unique Composite Keys, in this way a Dealer Y can't have two distinct prices to the same item.

Hope it helps!